# step by step guide to use the remote debugging feature in Chrome for Android on Windows

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, chrome-for-android

I've been looking through out the internet for a serious amount of time now for a working tutorial on how to enable the remote debugging feature which is built in to Chrome for Android, but I just can't get it to work.

Step three in [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging) says nothing to me. I've tried to paste `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote` into cmd, but it just says "adb is not an internal or external command". What am I doing wrong?

I do have the Android SDK installed, having installed the packages "Android SDK Tools", "Android SDK Platform-tools", "Google USB Driver" and "Google Web Driver".

Please, I need a step-by-step-from-the-very-basics tutorial on how to do this properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure adb is in your path...?

Comment: Oh, thank you! Great! I missed that. Sorry for not reading the instructions properly.
Once again, thank you! :)

Comment: +1 for listing the link to the guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that solved my problem was posted as a comment by Boris Smus on my initial post. I had missed to add the location of /platform-tools/ to my path in cmd. With that done all was working perfect! :)
Sorry for not reading the instructions firmly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about this YouTube vid.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4zpL4VBbuU

Comment: I've seen it. But that is on a mac. Will it work with the EXACT same commands in cmd as in terminal? aka. Should it work if I paste "adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_­remote" into cmd and hit enter?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)